# Products from the store displayed according to delivery date (woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce

I have a virtual store that sells products that are delivered on certain days of the week (Tuesday, Wednesday, Saturday). Some products are delivered within three days and others only on different days.

In the product registry an attribute called delivery availability was created in order to control this behavior.

How can I control what will be displayed in the shop (shop page) according to the selection of availability of delivery date?

Eg: When placing an order on a Monday the customer selects that the delivery date is next Saturday, ie, the store should only display the products with that availability.

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post in that language, or ask at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead. Thanks.

Comment: This is just logically not possible, as the delivery availability is made afterwards…

Comment: Can't you create custom meta field for product for deliverydate/availability and query products according to it?